Convexity of negative log-likelihood of exponential family distribution
Let $p(y; \theta^Tx) = b(y) \space \exp\big(\theta^T x y - a(\theta^T x)\big)$, where $x$ and $\theta$ are $d$-dimensional vectors and $y$ a scalar.
If I'm not mistaken, the negative log-likelihood should be:
$$ l(\theta) = -\sum_{i=1}^n log(b(y_i)) - \sum_{i=1}^n \theta^T x^i y_i + \sum_{i=1}^n a(\theta^T x^i) $$
The problem should boil down to proving that the Hessian of $l$ with respect to $\theta$ is positive semidefinite.
Again, if I'm not mistaken the Hessian is composed of these elements:
$$ \frac{\delta^2}{\delta \theta_k \delta \theta_j} l(\theta) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\delta^2}{\delta \theta_k \delta \theta_j} a(\theta^T x^i) x_j^i x_k^i $$
It should be possible to write the Hessian as $z z^T$ (which implies that for any compatible vector $x$, $x^T (z z^T) x \geq 0$).
This is where I'm stuck. I haven't been able to express the Hessian as the outer product of $z$. How do I go about proving that $H$ is PSD?

I'm having a little trouble with your notation, so just to clarify;  $x$ is really an $n \times d$ matrix, with $x^i$ being the $i^{th}$ row?  In which case, $x^i_j x^i_k$ is the same as $x_{ij} x_{ik}$ in the notation I'm more used to seeing?  But $\theta$ is a vector of length $d$, not with the same dimensionality as $x$, despite your first line?

No, $x$ is a $n \times 1$ vector. $x^i$ simply refers to the vector corresponding to the $i$-th observation. Sorry, I should have stated that I was using $x$ as a placeholder for any given observation. I just wrote it down the way it was written in my assignment.
